# how to select toggle on/off button in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am running E2E on my angular application using Protractor. How to write script for toggle button.

```
<span class="bootstrap-switch-handle-on bootstrap-switch-primary" style="width: 41px;">ON</span>
<span class="bootstrap-switch-label" style="width: 41px;">&nbsp;</span>
<span class="bootstrap-switch-handle-off bootstrap-switch-default" style="width: 41px;">OFF</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't guess the DOM of your page. Firstly, I'd rather not use xpath. IMHO in protractor `by` should be lowercase.

I assume that after clicking the element class of span changes.

maybe try sth like that:

```
const button = element(by.css('span.bootstrap-switch-primary'));
button.getAttribute('class').then((classes) => {
    if (classes.indexOf('bootstrap-switch-handle-on') === -1) {
        return button.click();
    }
}
```